# Outputting a project's output as embedded resource in another project in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, build-process, embedded-resource

I am using VS2013 with C# (3.5).

My setup is a .sln with 2 projects (both build a class library):

```
MySolution.sln
    |-- Project A (builds A.dll)
    |-- Project B (builds B.dll)
```

I would like to build the .sln in VS2013, such that:

1. Project A builds --> A.dll
2. A.dll will be added to Project B as an embedded resource.
3. Upon building the project B - the most up to date A.dll will be embedded in it.

**Is there any easy and robust way to achieve this through configuration in VS2013 ? (e.g: not resorting to MSBuild or any other build system).**

Comment: Why do you need to use it as embedded resources? If you refer A from B, then the output A.dll will automatically be copied to the output folder of B.dll or B.exe (whatever is the output)

Comment: If you are willing to embed types from A.dll to B.dll then this might help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409610.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I do not know if it works in VS2013.

Anyways using VS2019 this is possible by adding the dll as link:

- In the solution explorer right click on project B -> `Add` -> `Existing Item`.
- Then select the built A.dll file.
- Do not click on `Add` but click on the tiny bottom facing rectangle and click on `Add As link`.
- In the solution explorer select the newly added file and in its properties change the buld action to `Embedded Resource`.

Note: This process *works* but it is configuration dependent (Release/Debug mode).